# Studio compile error does not prompt the information

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Android Studio Clean Strange question
No prompt

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this problem will be fixed by doing the below step.

Go to

File->Setting->Gradle->Gradle Vm Option
For Android Studio 1.2

File->Setting->Build, Deployment &Execution->Build Tools->Gradle->Gradle Vm Option
, Now put this value -Xmx256m in the box, and hit the Apply button.

Comment: @jinwei apply this value than after tell me

Comment: Click "Gradle Console" for the log from Gradle.
Debug from the error messages
Mac: In Android Studio, go to:
"Preference"
"Build, Execution, Deployment"
"Compiler"
Add "--stacktrace" to "Command-line Options"
Note the error will usually be listed as the first line (improperly formatted for Android Studio Gradle console such as: